# Prove that $V$ is isomorphic to $W \times V/W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, vector-space-isomorphism

I have been asked to prove the following:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space of a field $K$ and $W$ be a subspace of $V$. Prove that $V$ is isomorphic to $W \times V/W$ (the direct product of $W$ and $V/W$).

Here is my proof thus far:

Define $\pi: V \rightarrow V/W$ by $\pi(v) = [v]$.

We need to show that $\pi$ is a linear map and that it is surjective and injective.

To show that $\pi$ is a linear map we must show that $\pi(a+b) = \pi(a) + \pi(b)$ and that $\pi(ka) = k\pi(a)$.

1. Take some $a, b \in V$. $\pi(a+b) = [a + b] = [a] + [b] = \pi(a) + \pi(b)$ by our definition of addition of equivalence classes.
2. Take some $a \in V$ and some $k \in \mathbb{F}$. Now, $\pi(ka) = [ka] = k \cdot [a] = k\pi(a)$ by our definition of multiplication of equivalence classes.

So, we have show that $\pi$ is a linear map and now we must show that it is injective and surjective.

To show that $\pi$ is surjective:

1. Take $[a] \in V/W$, where $[a]$ := {$v \in V | a-v \in W$}
2. Let $v = a$, and so, $a-a \in W$ which implies that $0 \in W$. Since $W$ is a subspace, we know by definition that $0 \in W$, and it follows that $\pi$ is surjective.

To show that $\pi$ is injective:

1. We know by definition that $\pi$ is injective if $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ implies that $a=b$.
2. Take $a,b \in V$ and assume that $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$. By definition we know this implies that $[a]=[b]$. This then implies that $a \sim b$, so we are done.

I feel confident that I showed that $\pi$ is a linear map correctly but I am worried about the part where I illustrate that $\pi$ is a linear map. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Just did. Thanks! @Shaun

Comment: The key idea is that subspaces are complemented, i.e. there exists a subspace $N$ such that $V  = W \oplus N$ (internal direct sum).  How do you show this, and how does it help?

Comment: You're welcome. In fact, [here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Hmm. Well I'm not familiar with internal direct sums but I am familiar with direct sums. I know that W + N is a direct sum if the W $\cap$ N = {0}. But....I have no idea how this helps.

Comment: do you by any chance know that $\dim(V/W)=\dim(V)-\dim(W)$?

Comment: I don't @JeskoHüttenhain

Comment: (fwiw, agra: What you've called a direct sum is precisely what fred meant by an internal direct sum. People sometimes say this to distinguish it from the "external direct sum" where $W$ and $N$ need not be subspaces of a "big" vector space [and therefore the notation $W\cap N$ would not even make sense].)

Comment: Thank you! @EricStucky But again, I ask what this has to do with the above. I guess I'm confused because I know that there is some relationship between quotient spaces and direct sums - specifically the zero vector but I don't really understand what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ of $W$ and extend it to a basis
$$
\{w_1,\dots,w_m,v_1,\dots,v_n\}
$$
of $V$. Now note that $\{[v_1],\dots,[v_n]\}$ is a basis for $V/W$.

Some more details. A vector $v\in V$ can be uniquely written as
$$
v=a_1w_1+\dots+a_mw_m+b_1v_1+\dots+b_nv_n
$$
Define $f(v)= a_1w_1+\dots+a_mw_m$ and prove this defines a linear map $f\colon V\to W$. Now consider also the projection map $\pi\colon V\to V/W$, $\pi(v)=[v]$ and prove that $F\colon V\to W\times V/W$,
$$
F(v)=(f(vj,\pi(v))
$$
Is the required isomorphism.

Comment: What does this have to do with isomorphisms? Are you trying to get me to use the fact that there exists an isomorphism between two vector spaces iff they have the same dimension? We have not proved that result in class so I am a bit wary of using it. I guess is it possible to go a different route with the proof and avoid using the above result?

Comment: @agra94 No, you can write any vector $v\in V$ as a linear combination of the basis; then take the “w”-part, call it $\pi(v)$ and consider $V\to W\times V/W$ defined by $v\mapsto(\pi(v),v+W)$.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still kind of confused. Why would we want to define $\pi(v)$ as mapping $v \in V \mapsto (\pi(v),v+W)$? I feel like what you are getting at is that I need to find some linear mapping and then show that it is injective and surjective, but I am confused at your choice of function.

Comment: @agra94 The map $\pi$ is from $V$ to $W$, so the other one is $f\colon V\to W\times V/W$, $f(v)=(\pi(v),v+W)$.

Comment: Hmm. I have updated my proof to show the new method I am trying. I used the definition of V/W using equivalence classes. If you don't mind I would really appreciate your input!

Comment: @agra94 Sorry, but that proof is wrong: your map $\pi$ is not injective unless $W=0$. About notation: your $[v)$ means the same as my $v+W$.