# Proving that for a vector space $V$ and $W \subset V$, $V \cong W \times V/W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove a statement made in Harvard's abstract algebra lecture series on youtube. The statement, paraphrased, is as follows:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $W \subset V$ a subspace. Then $V \cong W \times V/W$.

The lecturer states that this follows from previous result. After consulting an earlier post ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656000/prove-that-v-is-isomorphic-to-w-times-v-w)), I made some progress but am struggling with the full proof. The results that I'm taking for granted and which I've previously proved are as follows:

1. The projection map $\pi: V \to V/W$ sending $v \mapsto V/W$ is a surjective linear map.
2. If $(w_1, \ldots, w_m)$ is an ordered basis for $W$ (which I'll fix for the purposes of this proof), I can extend it to a basis $(w_1, \ldots, w_m, v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ for $V$. Then every $v \in V$, by spanning and linear independence of this basis, can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of these basis vectors. I will try to consistently use the notation $v = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m a_i w_i + \sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j v_j$.
3. The map $f: V \to W$ sending $v = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m a_i w_i + \sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j v_j$ to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m a_i w_i$ is well-defined (since this representation is unique) and linear.
4. The map $\Omega: V \to W \times V/W$ sending $v \mapsto (f(v), \pi(v))$ is linear, which is a consequence of linearity of $f$ and $\pi$.

I'm struggling with proving it is actually an isomorphism, though. I run into an immediate issue in proving surjectivity. Let's let $(w, v + W) \in W \times V/W$. Then I can write $w$ as a linear combination of the $W$ basis vectors or the full, extended basis for $V$. I believe this implies that the coefficients of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are $0$, since otherwise the representation relative to the full basis of $V$ would be non-zero: I'd have one linear combination of $w_1, \ldots w_m$ giving me $w$, and could let each of the coefficients of the $v$'s be $0$, so if there's any other representation where the coefficients of the $v$'s are non-zero, this would contradict linear independence of the full basis. So I'll write $w = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m c_i w_i$. Then $f(w) = w$. The second component is the problem. I may have $v \in V - W$, so I can't choose $v$ as my preimage, though if $v \in W$, this is fine. This $v$ is only a single representative of the coset $v + W$, so I'm able to choose any other vector $u \in V$ with $v - u \in W$. There isn't any guarantee that I'm going to be able to choose the same pre-image, however. (That is, I don't believe $\pi(w) = v + W$ is true in general.) So I'm stuck here.

Injectivity also seems to be a problem because neither $\pi$ nor $f$ are injective. There are multiple representatives I can choose for the equivalence class $v + W$, and given a vector in $W$, I have coefficients relative to $(w_1, \ldots, w_m)$. I can choose any coefficients for $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ and find a different preimage for the vector in $V$ under $f$ .

It seems that this map doesn't work, even though it appears "natural" and draws on previous results. I'd appreciate any help in sorting this out.

Comment: $\Omega$ is an isomorphism. Think about where $\Omega$ sends the basis vectors $w_1, \ldots, w_m, v_1, \ldots, v_n$.